# Clarity on Implementation of Continuation Monad Instance

Tags: haskell

Below is the code sample I tried for Continuation Monad

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont { rC :: (a -> r) -> r }

instance Functor (Cont r) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Cont r a -> Cont r b
  fmap f (Cont aCont) = Cont $ \k -> aCont (\a -> k (f a))

instance Applicative (Cont r) where
  pure :: a -> Cont r a
  pure a = Cont $ \k -> k a

  (<*>) :: Cont r (a -> b) -> Cont r a -> Cont r b
  Cont fCont <*> Cont aCont = Cont $ \k -> fCont (\f -> aCont (\a -> k (f a)))

instance Monad (Cont r) where
  return = pure

  (>>=) :: Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
  Cont aCont >>= f = Cont $ \k -> rC (aCont (\a -> f a)) (\b -> k b)
  -- f a :: Cont r b
  -- aCont :: (a -> r) -> r
  -- t = aCont (\a -> f a) :: Cont r b
  -- t' = rc t :: (b -> r) -> r
  -- k :: b -> r
  -- t' (\b -> k b) -> r
```

This is Failing with below error

```
<interactive>:158:52: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: r ~ Cont r b
    * In the expression: f a
      In the first argument of `aCont', namely `(\ a -> f a)'
      In the first argument of `rC', namely `(aCont (\ a -> f a))'
    * Relevant bindings include
        k :: b -> r (bound at <interactive>:158:30)
        f :: a -> Cont r b (bound at <interactive>:158:18)
        aCont :: (a -> r) -> r (bound at <interactive>:158:8)
        (>>=) :: Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
          (bound at <interactive>:158:14)
```

And when I changed the **bind** code as below it worked. Please help me with the type error.

```
  (>>=) :: Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
  Cont aCont >>= f = Cont $ \k -> aCont (\a -> rC (f a) (\b -> k b))
```

Comment: while learning, it might help using clearer names like `newtype Cont r a = MkCont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }`. Also, maybe use `br` for `k :: b -> r`, `arr` or `ar_r` for `foo :: (a -> r) -> r`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will follow that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you were simply getting confused - which I find very easy to do with continuations!

This definition:

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont { rC :: (a -> r) -> r }
```

defines 2 functions "for free":

```
Cont :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> Cont r a
rC :: Cont r a -> (a -> r) -> r
```

Then in your attempted definition of `>>=`, you had:

```
Cont aCont >>= f = Cont $ \k -> rC (aCont (\a -> f a)) (\b -> k b)
```

Here `aCont (\a -> f a)` is being used as the argument to `rC`, so must have type `Cont r a`. At the same time, since `Cont` is a constructor with the type shown above, from `Cont aCont` then GHC must assign to `aCont` the type `(a -> r) -> r`. This in turn means `f a` must have type `r`, while `a` has type `a -> r`.

But from the type of `>>=`, `f` must have type `a -> Cont r b`. So `f a` must simultaneously be of type `r` and `Cont r b`, and trying to make those two types the same clearly involves an infinite regress - which is exactly what GHC is telling you.

The details above aren't too important however. What seems obvious is that `aCont` was already "unwrapped" and you didn't need to apply the unwrapping function `rC` to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `r` types must match in the definition of the `>>=`

If your type was

```
type Cont' a = forall r . Cont r a
```

Your definition would be valid

```
bind  :: Cont' a -> (a -> Cont' b) -> Cont'  b
bind  (Cont aCont) f = Cont $ \k -> rC (aCont (\a -> f a)) (\b -> k b)
```

The cool thing is without newtype wrapper this definition is simply function application.

```
bind
  :: (forall r . (a -> r) -> r)
  -> (forall r . a -> (b -> r) -> r)
  -> (forall r . (b -> r) -> r)
bind a b = a b
```

Without using existential quantification  you should do explicitly pass continuations.

```
bind' :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> (b -> r) -> r) -> ((b -> r) -> r)
bind' a b cont = a (\a' -> b a' cont)
```

Finally with newtype wrapper

```
bind'' :: Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
bind'' a b = Cont $ \g -> rC  a (\a' -> rC (b a') g )
```